# Reset the value of observable when other observables change

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knockout and trying to build a new feature in our application using knockout (v3.2.0). The feature is a predicate where user can select a property and its return type on LHS and specify RHS value. Whenever the LHS value changes (or its return type), I want to reset the RHS value but it is not working as expected. Here is the code

```js
function Predicate(){
   var _predicate = this;
  _predicate.LHS = ko.observable();
  _predicate.RHS = ko.observable();
  _predicate.LHSReturnType = ko.observable();
  _predicate.LHS.subscribe(function (newVal) {
    this.RHS(null);
    //predicatePropertyMgr.CleanPredicateProperties();
    console.log(this.LHS() + ' ---- ' + this.LHSReturnType() + ' ------ ' + this.RHS());
    
  }, _predicate);
  
  _predicate.LHSReturnType.subscribe(function(){
    this.RHS(null);
      console.log(this.LHS() + ' ---- ' + this.LHSReturnType() + ' ------ ' + this.RHS());
  }, _predicate);
 
  _predicate.PropertyNames = ko.computed(function () {
            //return predicatePropertyMgr.GetAllProperties();
    return [{ DisplayName: 'Status', FieldName: 'StatusID' }, 
            { DisplayName: 'Due Date', FieldName: 'DueDate' }];
  });
  
  _predicate.AllowedReturnTypes = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
      let propName = _predicate.LHS();
      if(propName == 'StatusID')
      {
        return [{ ID: 1, Name: 'Text' }, 
            { ID: 2, Name: 'Number' }];
      }
      if(propName == 'DueDate')
      {
        return [{ ID: 3, Name: 'Date' }];
      }
      return [];
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
  });
  
  _predicate.PropertyOptions = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
      return [{ displayText: 'Any', value: 0 }, 
              { displayText: 'New', value: 1 }, 
              { displayText: 'InProgress', value: 2 }];
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
  });
   _predicate.RHSControlType = ko.computed({
     read: function () {
       let propName = _predicate.LHS();
       if (propName == 'StatusID') {
         return 'combo';
       }
       if (propName == 'DueDate') {
         return 'textbox';
       }
       return 'textbox';
     },
     deferEvaluation: true
   });
};

var vm = new Predicate();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
console.log(vm.LHS() + ' ---- ' + vm.LHSReturnType() + ' ------ ' + vm.RHS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select  data-bind="options:PropertyNames, value: LHS, optionsText:'DisplayName', optionsValue:'FieldName'"></select>
<!--
<select data-bind="options: AllowedReturnTypes, optionsText:'Name', optionsValue:'ID', value: LHSReturnType"></select>
-->
<!--ko if: RHSControlType() == 'textbox' || RHSControlType() == 'textArea'-->
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" data-bind="value: RHS" />
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko if: RHSControlType() == 'combo'-->
<select data-bind="options: PropertyOptions, optionsText:'displayText', optionsValue:'value', value: RHS"></select>
<!--/ko-->
```

I am sure I am missing something simple here. I am expecting when the text box renders, it should be empty. Is there an order how knockout evaluates computed observables? I did try to debug in chrome dev tools and the break points are hitting in proper sequence but it doesn't set the RHS to null. I was thinking may be RHSControlType is getting evaluated before LHS subscribe function can set RHS to null.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vabii/t2Lszjqm/

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the same observable (RHS) on the textbox and select box?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin If I have another variable for RHS for select, I have to keep track of true value of RHS. I am sending this data to server and serializing it to evaluate at later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem arises because the `value: RHS` exists on both the input and the select element. The value binding for select elements defaults to the selected element.  From the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html):

> Normally, when you use the value binding on a  element, it
>   means that you want the associated model value to describe which item
>   in the  is selected.

I suspect you're getting 0 in the text box because the select comes second and updates the binding. If you use a separate binding the issue goes away.

```
_predicate.RHS2 = ko.observable();

<select data-bind="options: PropertyOptions, optionsText:'displayText', optionsValue:'value', value: RHS2"></select>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/t2Lszjqm/9/)

Comment: That explains it. But I don't want to have another variable to track my RHS. I used optionCaption binding for select that sets initial value of RHS as undefined. Now it works properly whenever I change LHS.

Comment: Maybe you could use subscribe on RHS and update RHS2